# Simple Injector inject dependency into custom global authentication filters and OWIN middle ware OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, action-filter, simple-injector, .net-attributes

I used Simple Injector as our Ioc container; we have two problems.

1. We want to inject into our custom authentication filter; we read the post of converting attribute to a passive attribute: [Convert Attribute into a passive](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98). But we can't convert custom authentication filter attribute into a passive.

   ```
   public class BearerAuthentication : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
   {
      public async Task AuthenticateAsync(
          HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {

       }
      public Task ChallengeAsync(
          HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {

       }
   }
   ```
2. We want to inject dependency into OWin middleware OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider; we know we can use begin execution context scope, but we want an elegant solution.

   ```
   using (Ioc.Container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
   {

   }
   ```

Updated

```
public interface IAuthenticationFilter<TAttribute> where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
public  class BearerAuthenticationFilter : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter<BearerAuthenticationFilter>
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationBusinessEngine _authenticationBusinessEngine;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public BearerAuthenticationFilter(IAuthenticationBusinessEngine authenticationBusinessEngine, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _authenticationBusinessEngine = authenticationBusinessEngine;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

         throw new NotImplementedException();  

        }
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
public class AuthenticationFilterDispatcher : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable> _container;
    public AuthenticationFilterDispatcher(Func<Type, IEnumerable> container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var descriptor = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var attributes = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Attribute>(true)
            .Concat(descriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Attribute>(true));

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            var filterType = typeof(IAuthenticationFilter<>).MakeGenericType(attribute.GetType());
            var filters = _container.Invoke(filterType);

            foreach (dynamic actionFilter in filters)
            {
                await actionFilter.AuthenticateAsync(context, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "But we can't convert custom authentication filter attribute into a passive.". Why?

Comment: Hello, Steven; I already read your post about passive attributes but in case of authentication filter;The attribute must implement IAuthenticationFilter and in your post you depend on OnActionExecuting method but in my case, the AuthenticateAsync and ChallengeAsync runs even before your ActionFilterDispatcher

Comment: In that case you can create a filter that is registered in the pipeline before all other filters. This filter can use its own IAutFilter<T>.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Hi Steven; I am waiting your feedback

Comment: Your question about your middlewhere issue is too vague. Please create a new question for this on Stackoverflow with more detailed information about what you you have, what you are trying to achieve and what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent code for working with `IAuthenticationFilter` is:

```cs
public interface IAuthenticationFilter<TAttribute> where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    Task AuthenticateAsync(TAttribute attribute, HttpAuthenticationContext context);
}

public class AuthenticationFilterDispatcher : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable> container;
    public AuthenticationFilterDispatcher(Func<Type, IEnumerable> container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context,
        CancellationToken token) {
        var descriptor = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var attributes = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes<Attribute>(true)
            .Concat(descriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Attribute>(true));

        foreach (var attribute in attributes) {
            Type filterType = typeof(IAuthenticationFilter<>)
                .MakeGenericType(attribute.GetType());
            IEnumerable filters = this.container.Invoke(filterType);

            foreach (dynamic actionFilter in filters) {
                await actionFilter.AuthenticateAsync((dynamic)attribute, context);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, 
        CancellationToken token) { }

    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return true; } }
}
```

Registration is done as follows:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(
    new AuthenticationFilterDispatcher(container.GetAllInstances));

// For Simple Injector 2.x:
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IAuthenticationFilter<>),
    container.RegisterAll, 
    new[] { typeof(IAuthenticationFilter<>).Assembly });

// For Simple Injector 3.x:
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IAuthenticationFilter<>),
    new[] { typeof(IAuthenticationFilter<>).Assembly });
```

Now instead of making your attributes active, you can make the attribute passive and implement the required logic inside an `IAuthenticationFilter<MyPassiveAttribute>` implementation.

Your attribute and new component might look like this:

```cs
// NOTE: This attribute does not derive from anything Web API specific,
// just from Attribute
public class RequiresBearerAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute
{
    // put here properties if required
}

public class BearerAuthenticationFilter 
    : IAuthenticationFilter<RequiresBearerAuthenticationAttribute>
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationBusinessEngine _authenticationBusinessEngine;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public BearerAuthenticationFilter(
        IAuthenticationBusinessEngine authenticationBusinessEngine, 
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _authenticationBusinessEngine = authenticationBusinessEngine;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(RequiresBearerAuthenticationAttribute attribute, 
        HttpAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // TODO: Behavior here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steven;Thanks for your help; i already update my code according to your advise but there is compile error as the attribute must have a parameter less(default constructor); please see the updates in the post and tell me how to solve it; Also, i want to solve the second issue(OWIN middle ware issue)

Comment: You are mixing things up. Passive attribute means: no behavior. You should split data and behavior. Your `IAuthenticationFilter<T>` implementation should not inherit from `Attribute`.

Comment: @yo2011: See my update. I added the attribute and the component implementations as example.

Comment: Thanks Steven for your great help; I think the attribute RequiresBearerAuthenticationAttribute  doesn't have any meaningful as i have no data to carry so , i don't need it; only i want to implement IAuthenticationFilter with the two methods and all of my logic will be on BearerAuthenticationFilter; Also, i want to fix the second issue (OWIN middleware code)

Comment: I fxied the second issue using  var dependencyResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDependencyResolver>();
            using (dependencyResolver.BeginScope())
            {}