# Inject Logger in IExceptionFilter with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I'm using Simple Injector in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI application. I have an IExceptionFilter in which I want to log the error. My code is below (working), but is this the correct way? It looks like lot of work

```
public class HttpGlobalExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public HttpGlobalExceptionFilter(Infrastructure.Common.ILogger logger)
    {
        // This is my own logger, implemented along the lines as mentioned here:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243485/
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Irrelevant stuff
        // ...

        var error = $"An error occured: {context.Exception.Message}";
        this.logger.LogError(error);
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs ConfigureServices(), I have:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new SimpleInjectorExceptionFilterDispatcher(
        this.container.GetInstance<IExceptionFilter>));
    // ...
});
```

instead of

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<HttpGlobalExceptionFilter>();
    // ...
});
```

In my bindings:

```
container.Register<IExceptionFilter, HttpGlobalExceptionFilter>();
```

Finally, the dispatcher:

```
public sealed class SimpleInjectorExceptionFilterDispatcher : IExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly Func<IExceptionFilter> exceptionFilterFunc;

    public SimpleInjectorExceptionFilterDispatcher(
        Func<IExceptionFilter> exceptionFilterFunc)
    {
        this.exceptionFilterFunc = exceptionFilterFunc;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        this.exceptionFilterFunc.Invoke().OnException(context);
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go about getting Simple Injector work with different components of ASP.NET? This is complex setup, and I would prefer to have something simpler so that all developers can easily understand the code.

Also, can I totally avoid Microsoft DI and use Simple Injector (and expect simpler configurations?)

References:

[Simple Injector inject dependency into custom global authentication filters and OWIN middle ware OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953921/simple-injector-inject-dependency-into-custom-global-authentication-filters-and)

[Simple Injector: Register ILogger<T> by using ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243485/simple-injector-register-iloggert-by-using-iloggerfactory-createloggert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `HttpGlobalExceptionFilter`'s dependencies (currently `ILogger`) are singletons, you could simplify your solution by cutting out the `SimpleInjectorExceptionFilterDispatcher`. This would reduce the solution to the following:

```
options.Filters.Add(new HttpGlobalExceptionFilter(new LoggerAdapter()));
```

This constructs the filter and its dependencies manually. You can also resolve it from the Container. To make sure that you don't accidentally create [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/), you should make sure that you register `HttpGlobalExceptionFilter` as `Singleton`:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<HttpGlobalExceptionFilter>();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(this.container.GetInstance<HttpGlobalExceptionFilter>());
});
```

Instead of using MVC filters, you can also go one level up and define a middleware component and hook it up as described [here](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore#wiring-custom-middleware) in the Simple Injector documentation. This simplifies the registration even further, although it might complicate your implementation, depending on your exact needs.

This means rewriting your `HttpGlobalExceptionFilter` to a middleware component. This could look something as follows:

```
public sealed class HttpGlobalExceptionMiddleware
    : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IMiddleware
{
    private readonly Infrastructure.Common.ILogger logger;

    public HttpGlobalExceptionMiddleware(ILogger logger) =>
        this.logger = logger;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = $"An error occured: {ex.Message}";
            this.logger.LogError(error);            
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Using Simple Injector's `UseMiddleware` extension method, you can register it Simple Injector and at the same time add it to ASP.NET Core's middleware pipeline:

```
app.UseMiddleware<HttpGlobalExceptionMiddleware>(container);
```